# JS Confirm Message

Tags: javascript, loops, alert, confirm

I am new to JavaScript and I'm currently creating a password generator for a project. I am running into a problem where when the user is prompted with `confirm` messages to select their ideal password criteria. I want to return an `alert` message to the window with a `loop` function if they don't choose at least one option. Here is what I have so far.

```
// function: when you click on generate button it prompts messages to select password criteria. 
var generateBtnPrompt = function () {
    var confirmNumber = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate numbers in your password");
    var confirmLowerCase = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate lowerCase characters in your password");
    var confirmUpperCase = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate upperCase characters in your password");
    var confirmSymbols = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate symbols characters in your password");
    //parseInt convert a string into an integer
    var charLength = parseInt(prompt("How many characters would you like your password to be? Please choose a number from (8-128)"));
};
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you're trying to do.  While `confirmNumber` is false and `confirmLowerCase` is false and `confirmUpperCase` is false and `confirmSymbols` is false and `charLength` is 0 alert something?

Comment: "I want to return an `alert` message to the window with a `loop` function". What would be the loop function's role? Please, clarify that.

Comment: Newcomer tip: Use ES6+ syntax where you avoid global variables. Use `const` as much as possible, `let` if needed, and skip `var` entirely. Don't listen to teachers or tutorials that still use `var`, it means they are very likely outdated in other areas of the language, too.

Comment: @j08691 sorry to make it look that way but being NEW to this field and trying to learn it, I attempted several solutions but they(functions) weren't working so I erased all the irrelevant syntax and kept what was working so far!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [`Logical OR`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator (`||`) to check that at least one of the variables are true.

> **MDN Web Docs:**
> The logical OR (`||`) operator (logical disjunction) for a set of
> operands is `true` if and only if one or more of its operands is true.

And [`recursion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) to re-run the function if none of the variables are true.

**Like this:**

```js
if (!(confirmNumber || confirmLowerCase || confirmUpperCase)) {
  alert("You need to pick at least one!");
  return generateBtnPrompt()
}
```

---

Full code:

```js
var generateBtnPrompt = function () {
    var confirmNumber = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate numbers in your password");
    var confirmLowerCase = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate lowerCase characters in your password");
    var confirmUpperCase = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate upperCase characters in your password");
    var confirmSymbols = confirm("Click 'OK' to generate symbols characters in your password");
    
    if (!(confirmNumber || confirmLowerCase || confirmUpperCase)) {
      alert("You need to pick at least one!");
      return generateBtnPrompt()
    }
    
    var charLength = parseInt(prompt("How many characters would you like your password to be? Please choose a number from (8-128)"));
};

generateBtnPrompt()
```

Comment: Terrible use of recursion.  Any loop construct is going to be just as effective without risking a possibly unlimited stack depth.

Comment: @Tibrogargan IMO recursion is more concise and readable than a loop in this example. I'm not sure it's possible for OP to decline 38612 confirm boxes to reach the Maximum call stack size.

Comment: A test framework would find it trivial.  It's just bad practice to have a recursive function that isn't guaranteed to complete.  This is precisely why stack based implementations are recommended for most use cases.  Besides that, you probably want to fix the logic error and the scoping problems.